# Why does my program go into endless loop when char array is overfilled?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm attempting to write a program in C++ that lets user enter a positive integer and a name into array with fixed size and print them out. The program seems to work correctly when I enter correct data from the first time of launching the program.

The problem I'm experiencing is when entering incorrect value for Char array (Exceeding the character count). If I enter incorrect value for char array, it gives a warning message as expected, but once I enter the correct size word, the program goes into endless loop of asking for already entered values.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 1;
    int num = 0; // variable for positive integer
    char name[31]; //char array to store name inside

    while(count != 0){

        cout << "Please enter the number: " << endl;
        cin >> num;
        while(num < 1){
            cout << "Number must be a positive integer!" << endl;  //Loop that checks whether the 
            cin >> num;                                           // entered number is a positive 
        }                                                        //  integer.

        cout << "Please enter the name: " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        while(strlen(name) > 30){                                        //Loop that checks whether the
           cout << "Name exceeds the allowed character count!" << endl; //entered name exceeds the
           cin >> name;                                                // allowed character count.
        }

        --count;
    };

    cout << num << " " << name;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand why does my program go into endless loop if I enter an incorrect value first and the correct value afterwards? Is it something to do with exceeding the character count for array?

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: If you exceed the size of the `name` array, that's undefined behavior. Your code is basically trying to check for UB, and that's just not possible.

Comment: And that's why basically everyone uses `std::string` instead of fixed size arrays.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub - read the links at the bottom as well.

Comment: Writing out of range of `name` can overwrite `count` on the stack, which causes "endless" loop. Just a possible explanation, what can happen at the assembly/instruction level.

Comment: @David It's UB, plain and simple. *Any* behaviour is possible. You really cannot even *try* to reason about it. Not should you really try. Fixing the UB is the only sane way forward.

Comment: *I'm trying to understand why does my program go into endless loop* -- And this is exactly how hackers create havoc in a program by exploiting a buffer overrun.  All someone would have to do is enter more characters than your array can handle, and you now have a security hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop is problematic:

```
 while(strlen(name) > 30) {                                        //Loop that checks whether the
       cout << "Name exceeds the allowed character count!" << endl; //entered name exceeds the
       cin >> name;                                                // allowed character count.
 }
```

The `strlen()` will return 31 if there are 31 characters *followed* by a `'\0'`. So that's already more than your 31-element long array can hold. But that's not the smallest issue - you are running into an undefined behavior territory as soon as you load more chars from `cin` than your array's size - as of C++17, `cin` will happily write past the capacity of a c-style array if you tell it to do so.

I suggest you use `std::string`s instead of raw C arrays. They take care of the null-terminated string technicalities for you.

Comment: reading to a `char *` will always append a `'\0'` at the end of input, no problem here. Only problem is writing out of bounds, because you can't possibly check the length of an array from a pointer. C++17 changed nothing about this fact, but the behaviour will change in C++20 (overload for `char *` will be completely removed).

Comment: @churill Thanks for pointing that out. I really should start checking everything on cppreference before I post that type of nonsense.